# How to write to the Cloud Firestore using Node JS Cloud Function from Complex JSON Webhook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Webhook that delivers a complex JSON payload to my Cloud Function URL, and writes that JSON to collections & documents within my Cloud Firestore.

My Cloud Function looks something like:

```js
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
     await admin.firestore().collection("testCollection").doc().set({
          nameOfFieldFromFirestore: data.nameOfFieldFromJson,
]);
```

This works when its a simple JSON, for example: one that isn't heavily nested.

What I don't understand, is how to format this Node.JS Google Cloud Function to accept a field from a complex JSON that is nested.

I believe the Node.JS Runtime on Google Cloud Functions uses the Express Middleware HTTP framework.

Sample JSON:

```json
"id": "1",
"people": {
     "id": "1",
}
```

I know how to return the id in line 1. I'm unsure how to return the id in line 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want add whole webhook payload as it is then you can just pass that object in `set()`:

```
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const payload = req.body
 
  await admin.firestore().collection("testCollection").doc().set(payload)
  res.status(200).end()
);
```

If you want a specific (e.g. id in provided JSON) you can access that like this:

```
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const payload = req.body

  await admin.firestore().collection("testCollection").doc().set({
    someField: payload.people.id
  })
  res.status(200).end()
);
```

A Firestore document is like a JSON object so you can keep nesting maps that way upto a [maximum depth of 20](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#:%7E:text=Maximum%20depth%20of%20fields%20in%20a%20map%20or%20array).

Comment: It appears that your second code block has my solution. I need to specify payload.people.id and for a more nested complex JSON, I should just follow this pattern: nest1.nest.2.nest.3.id until I get to my desired JSON field.

Comment: @StephenStilwell yes that's correct. That's the dot notation to access nested properties. You can also use [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: do you have any suggestions for securing a cloud function like this? I'm worried about the JSON data leaking or others getting access to the cloud function URL endpoint.